# Get all Users Circles and then People in side them Google Plus android

Tags: android

Hi i am trying to get all circles i have for Google plus account. I authenticated my app using Google Plus Sign In Button.

Now i want to access all circles the logged in user has
[Circle Information Link](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/people)

How to get list of circles with Google plus api for android

Answer (score 0):

[To get list of circles](https://developers.google.com/+/domains/circles/listing):

```
import java.util.List;
import com.google.api.services.plusDomains.model.Circle;
import com.google.api.services.plusDomains.model.CircleFeed;

PlusDomains.Circles.List listCircles = plusDomains.circles().list("me");
listCircles.setMaxResults(5L);
CircleFeed circleFeed = listCircles.execute();
List<Circle> circles = circleFeed.getItems();

// Loop until no additional pages of results are available.
while (circles != null) {
  for (Circle circle : circles) {
    System.out.println(circle.getDisplayName());
  }

  // When the next page token is null, there are no additional pages of
  // results. If this is the case, break.
  if (circleFeed.getNextPageToken() != null) {
    // Prepare the next page of results
    listCircles.setPageToken(circleFeed.getNextPageToken());

    // Execute and process the next page request
    circleFeed = listCircles.execute();
    circles = circleFeed.getItems();
  } else {
    circles = null;
  }
}
```

[To get people inside circles](https://developers.google.com/+/domains/circles/people):

```
import com.google.api.services.plusDomains.model.PeopleFeed;

String circleId = "a1234b";

PlusDomains.People.ListByCircle listPeople = plusDomains.people().listByCircle(circleId);
listPeople.setMaxResults(100L);

PeopleFeed peopleFeed = listPeople.execute();
System.out.println("Google+ users circled:");

// This example only displays one page of results.
if(peopleFeed.getItems() != null && peopleFeed.getItems().size() > 0 ) {
  for(Person person : peopleFeed.getItems()) {
    System.out.println("\t" + person.getDisplayName());
  }
}
```

Comment: i cant refer to PlusDomains class, do i need to import some other jar to do so ?

Comment: @Bora Please follow this link: https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/getting-started

Comment: yes i am following this article , and using Google play services to do all api calls. However i am not able to import PlusDomains , :(

Comment: I have added "google-api-services-plusDomains.jar" in my project now i can reference PlusDomain class , but i to initialize this class ?